# May a Moroccan student work in Spain?

Tags: spain, work-permit

In 2022, I read [about an update](https://balcellsgroup.com/es/reforma-ley-extranjeria/) to [Spain's immigration law](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_Extranjer%C3%ADa_de_Espa%C3%B1a) which would permit [people with student visas to work for 30 hours a week](https://balcellsgroup.com/es/visado-estudiante-en-espana/).
I've read the [revised version of this law](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2000-544&p=20230323&tn=0), notably article 33, and haven't
found any mention about it.

Why is there no mention of the 30 hours in this law? (I see it refers to conditions established in regulations.) Is it in another law? Can Moroccan students work in Spain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regulation that creates the 30-hour restriction is found in Royal Decree ("Real Decreto") 629/2022 from July 26, 2022, presented in [the Official State Bulletin ("Boletín Oficial del Estado") from July 27, 2022](https://boe.es/boe/dias/2022/07/27/pdfs/BOE-A-2022-12504.pdf). See the new art. 42, paragraph 2:

> La actividad laboral no podrá ser superior a las treinta horas semanales
>
> > Work activity may not exceed thirty hours per week.